# Configure htaccess to use Angular and PHP routing

Tags: php, angular, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to use Angular 4 and PHP routing, but I'm not able to configure it in order to use both at the same time. I could make it work with one or the other, but not both.

This is my folder structure:

```
root
│ index.html
│ vendor.bundle.js    
| [..other angular files..]  
│
└─api
│  │ index.php
│  │ init.php
│  │
│  └─vendor
└─assets
└─[..other project files..]
```

On the file `api/index.php` is where I'm setting the PHP route.

---

So, when I use this `.htaccess`, the PHP route **works** as expected, but the Angular route doesn't work when I refresh the page, because it treats as a PHP route.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule . api/index.php [L]

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

---

I tried to change the `.htaccess` to redirect only if the url being called contain the route `/api/`, but it didn't worked. Like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} api
    RewriteRule . api/index.php [L]

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

With this code, the Angular route works, even when I refresh the page, but the PHP route never redirects to the index.php file, so it always return null.

What do I need to do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't know a lot about htaccess, I don't know if this answer is 100% right, but I managed to make it work.

What I did was to move the line `RewriteBase /` to the top and remove the `RewriteRule ^index.html..`, with a final `.htaccess` that looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} api
RewriteRule . api/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now this is working as expected. I'll leave the question open in case someone has a better answer.